# I am not getting antiforgery token name in angular js to mvc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

```
$http
  .defaults
  .headers
  .common['X-XSRF-Token'] = angular.element('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').attr('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean. The token is automatically set as a header based on the XSRF cookie. It's up to you to set the cookie when you want to.

Try looking into the documentation -  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#cross-site-request-forgery-xsrf-protection

If that doesn't help can you clarify your issue a little more?